# Filter subform table with textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am trying to filter a subform with a textbox.

I have a query to show table records in the subform and I have the criteria to filter the table, but when I type in the textbox to filter the sub form it only shows me one record with that name. I need it to show me all the names.

The criteria for my query is below.

```
Like "*" & [Forms]![frmPlanningForecast]![FETextbox].[Text] & "*"
```

I then have an OnChange event on the textbox to requery the subform.

As mentioned above I need it to show me all the records matching what i have typed, not just one.

When I use the filter option within the table itself(Dropdown box on the field header) and select the filter from there, it works great. But I need it to be typed into a textbox.

The picture attached will show you what I mean, I have "EQ" typed in the text box but it has only returned 1 record when their are 15 called "EQ" on the table.
[image: Example]

Comment: It doesn't only show one record. It shows 173, so your filter cannot be operational. Also, use the Value property, not the Text property in the filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add single quotes around `Like` parameter:

```
Like "'*" & [Forms]![frmPlanningForecast]![FETextbox] & "*'"
```

and second - Access has an old bug: if you refer in the query to form field like you did, it doesn't renew the value, used for criteria during Requery, you always will receive the same results. Workaround - replace reference to field by global function, which returns textbox value or use dynamic generating of RecordSource for subform.

Global function example:

```
Public Function GetFE() As Variable
    GetFE = [Forms]![frmPlanningForecast]![FETextbox]
End Function
```

Place it in any standard VBA module. Then your `Like` will look like this:

```
Like "'*" & GetFE() & "*'"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for you answer. I'm not quite sure how to do the last part, about the global function. Would you be able to help me on that?

Comment: Updated the answer. I also removed [Text], Thanks @Gustav for suggestion

Comment: I've followed what you said but when I run the query is says the GetFE is undefined. Any ideas why?

Comment: Looks like you placed GetFE function to the form's module, not to the standard (VBA editor Insert->Module).

Comment: I used "Form_frmPlanningForecast.FETextbox.text" in my function to get this working, great workaround, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier method and just wanted to let others know.

Instead of using criteria I used the following vba code.

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , (FETextbox = qryPlannedHours.LeadFE), SubFormPF
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but if user wants to use built-in filtering feature of subform (after right click on subform cell or header), it will reset your filtering.

Answer (score -1):

In older versions of Access, didn't there used to be an option in the query to use the sum field something like this:
[Formnane].[TextField]

I know that's very simplistic and I don't fully recall how to use it but it was something like that,  simple and straight forward if you're not a VB user. Forgive my lack of conviction,  I've used it before but it was 20 years ago.

Comment: Please only post answers if you're confident they're helpful. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is a *knowledge* base and many future visitors may land here.